# Pass additional data to onActivityResult (taking picture with camera)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

When we add mediastore.EXTRA_OUTPUT with a uri, I know the intent data is null. It is non-null only when returning a thumbnail of the image. However I have 3 imageViews which the user can tap to click a picture. The picture clicked must be displayed on that particular imageView.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.iv_rx1:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case R.id.iv_rx2:
                File f2 = getOutputMediaFile();
                Uri uri2 = Uri.fromFile(f2);
                selectImage(uri2);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case R.id.iv_rx3:
                File f3 = getOutputMediaFile();
                Uri uri3 = Uri.fromFile(f3);
                selectImage(uri3);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case R.id.iv_rx4:
                File f4 = getOutputMediaFile();
                Uri uri4 = Uri.fromFile(f4);
                selectImage(uri4);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void selectImage(Uri uri) {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                "Cancel"};
        final Uri uri1=uri;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle("Add picture of Prescription");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri1);
                    intent.putExtra(PRESCRIPTION_URI_INTENT, uri1.getPath());
                    Log.d("URI VALUE", uri1.getPath());
                    startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }

The on Activity Result for the same

     @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                    case Constants.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
                        //String locationImage= intent.getStringExtra(PRESCRIPTION_URI_INTENT);

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation);
                        imageView.setBitmap(bitmap);
                        //Want to change the image view to which bitmap must be added based on which image view the user clicks on
                        break;

                    case Constants.REQUEST_GALLERY:
                        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(mContext, newConfirmPrescriptionAct.class);
                        galleryIntent.putExtra(IMAGE_PATH_AS_STRING, selectedImageUri.toString());
                        galleryIntent.putExtra(Constants.IMAGE_SOURCE_TYPE, Constants.REQUEST_GALLERY);                        
                        galleryIntent.putExtra(DOES_CONTAIN_ONLY_OTC, false);
                        startActivity(galleryIntent);
                        break;
                }//Close switch statement

            } else {
                Log.d("Error ", "user canceled !");
            }
        } //Continues for some other options (not to do with the camera)
```

where `String imageLocation = uri1.getPath()` contains the path to where the image was saved.

I am able to click a picture and add it to one image view but not sure how to modify this to handle multiple clicks on different image Views. One solution I thought of was to change the `request code` and add information regarding which view is to be used and add relevant switch statements. Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: I feel there is no problem with your approach of sending different request code and handling with switch. Go Ahead with this.

Comment: OK I will go a head with that and see how it pans out. However, If I were to add the image views dynamically from the code, i.e. the user can keep clicking a button to add more and more image views, then in that case since I will not know how many image views are there, I cannot keep so many different request codes for the same.

Comment: You can still achieve this. You can assign a tag to dynamically created views and pass the tag code as request code . In onActivityResult any how you will have tagCode , and you can findViewByTag and assign the image. No need to swicth statement in that case. Also other way is you can put imageview in recyclerview and it will be per row basis which is very easy to handle.

Comment: The recyclerview is a good solution but the problem is I want to pass the uri location of these images to the next activity upon click of a button. If I use a recyclerview and paste the camera code inside that, then I wont be able to retrieve the image location of each row in which an image has been clicked. Unless there is a way around it.